# SCHED_IDLE not valid in sched_setscheduler()

Tags: c, process, scheduler

When I run `chrt -m`, I see different policy types:

```
SCHED_OTHER min/max priority    : 0/0
SCHED_FIFO min/max priority     : 1/99
SCHED_RR min/max priority       : 1/99
SCHED_BATCH min/max priority    : 0/0
SCHED_IDLE min/max priority     : 0/0
SCHED_DEADLINE min/max priority : 0/0
```

However, when I use `sched_setscheduler(pid_num, SCHED_IDLE, &sp);` in the C code, I get the following error:

```
error: ‘SCHED_IDLE’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘SCHED_RR’?
```

Any idea on how to fix that?

A sample code is shown below

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int pid_num = getpid();
    struct sched_param sp = { .sched_priority = 99 };
    int ret = sched_setscheduler(pid_num, SCHED_IDLE, &sp);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

System information is shown below:

```
$ uname -r
5.13.0-27-generic
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Comment: Please show us a small program that produces this compiler error.

Comment: 1. `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before any header includes. 2. Use `sched_priority` = `0`; as you've found out; it should be within [min..max] range. You need to share MRE to meet SO rules.

Comment: You should also mention what OS you're using.

Comment: Please see the updated post.

Comment: Thanks. Another question: what flags are you passing to the compiler? In particular, any `-std=XXX` one?

Comment: Only `-O3` I used.

Comment: Okay, on my older Ubuntu system, I get the same error and can get it to compile by also including `<linux/sched.h>`. I can't find any documentation anywhere that this is needed to use the Linux-specific schedulers, though, or just a hack. If I do find something I can refer to, I'll make this an answer.

Comment: @Shawn: I also tested by including two headers: `#include <sched.h>` and `#include <linux/sched.h>`. The compilation error is now fixed and I set that to SCHED_IDLE. However, I added `sched_getscheduler` and the returned value was SCHED_OTHER. That means SCHED_IDLE is the treated the same as SCHED_OTHER. I don't know if they are technically the same, but `chrt -m` they are two different things. Would you please verify that?

Comment: Did you fix the out of range priority and check to see if `sched_setscheduler()` succeeds or returns an error?